# How to use Custom or Keycloak Key Manager in the Try Out Console in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

By default, Resident key Manager is selected for the try-out console ->
[image]

If I disable Resident Key Manager in the WSO2 admin console, It does not allow me to create any token ->
[image]

Is there any configuration available to use the Custom/Keycloak key manager for the try-out console ??

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the resident KM you can configure a 3rd party KM. Since you are interested in Keycloak please refer to https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/

Please note that this is for APIM 4.1.0. Depending on your APIM version you can select the relevant document version.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, disabling the resident KM gives the warning -> "Try it console is only accessible via the default key manager. But the default key manager is disabled at the moment". Is there any way I can change the default to my Keycloak Key manager ?? I have followed the URI you have shared for setting up Keycloak as a Key Manager..

Comment: I have followed the same URL you have shared for configuration but when I disable Resident Key Manager, I got the following warning on the Try out page -> "Try it console is only accessible via the default key manager. But the default key manager is disabled at the moment".

Comment: any leads with the updates I have shared ??

Answer (score 0):

Adding the fix (below) in the deployment.toml has resolved our issue.

```
[authentication.framework.extensions] 
provisioning_handler = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.provisioning.impl.SystemRolesRetainedProvisionHandler"
```

In our case, we remove all applications created prior to the issue.

for choice custom key manager follow below:

In the API Publisher, navigate to the API you've selected or created, and go to the "Edit" section of the API configuration.

publisher -> runtime section -> Application level security -> Configure the key manager -> Permission selected -> choice keycloak/custom key-manager (not selected Resident Key Manager)